# Discord.js: Checking Bot Permissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is probably a nub question, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to make my bot check if it has a permission, and send a message if does not. I'm guessing it like this code to check it a member has a permission:

```
message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")
```

Is it like that to get a bots permissions? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9):

`message.member` gets the [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object of the author who sent the message. Looks like you actually want to get the GuildMember object of the client instead. You can do this by doing [`<Client>.guild.me`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=me) and then call .hasPermission(...) on this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if the bot has a permission you can do something like:

```
if(message.guild.me.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS"))
    console.log("I can mute members!!")
else
    console.log("I CAN'T mute members!")
```

F.M.

Answer (score 1):

```
message.guild.me.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")
```

Comment: Please add more details to the solution. Also, please follow StackOverflow guidelines - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: put some more explanations

Comment: @Harshit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer would be for answers. The link you posted would apply to questions. Another good tip would be to always read a page before you link it.

Answer (score 1):

In **discord.js V13** you can check for permissions this way:

```
 if (message.member.permissions.has("MUTE_MEMBERS")){
    // ....
 } else { 
    //....
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!message.member.hasPermission("PERMISSION") return message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command")
```

Embeds:

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("No Permission")
.setDescription("You don't have permission to use this command")

if(!message.member.hasPermission("PERMISSION") return message.channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: For checking bot permission same thing with another variable